# Mockito findByIdOrNull issue

Tags: java, unit-testing, jpa, kotlin, mockito

I have a test like this:

```
    @Test
    fun `can execute`() {
        whenever(countryRepository.findByIdOrNull("DE")).thenReturn(germany)
        underTest.execute()
    }
```

This test fails with the following error message:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
Country cannot be returned by findById()
findById() should return Optional
***
If you're unsure why you're getting above error read on.
Due to the nature of the syntax above problem might occur because:
1. This exception *might* occur in wrongly written multi-threaded tests.
   Please refer to Mockito FAQ on limitations of concurrency testing.
2. A spy is stubbed using when(spy.foo()).then() syntax. It is safer to stub spies - 
   - with doReturn|Throw() family of methods. More in javadocs for Mockito.spy() method.
```

Pretty sure this might be an issue with Mockito as I am not using `findbyId` but using `findByIdOrNull` as this is more suitable for kotlin. I do not want to change the code to fix a test.

can you please help me with a way to get rid of this issue or to work around this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently:

> Mockito doesn't support the mocking of static methods, at least not in
>   the near future.
>   https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/1481

So the [extension code](https://github.com/sdeleuze/spring-data-commons/blob/b221e943ec88c1880f1be4093f2db4ae1436f1be/src/main/kotlin/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepositoryExtensions.kt) is actually being executed rather than mocked.

One resolution may be to just let the code execute and instead of mocking `findByIdOrNull` just mock the underlying `findById` (to return an optional).

**Edit**

..or use [MockK](https://mockk.io/) as the link suggests!

Answer (score 0):

Return type for your `findById` method must be an `Optional` (Java 8). You can specify to return an optional of country like below.

```
Optional<Country> countryOptional = Optional.ofNullable(country);
when(findById(any())).thenReturn(countryOptional);
```

Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: The thing is I was not mocking `findById` but `findByIdOrNull`